# How do I send `MailMessage` that was stored in a `SpecifiedPickupDirectory`

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailmessage

I am storing Emails in a Directory, like the following.  How do I go about, programatically, sending those at a later time, say an `event` of some sorts

`smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\EmailHoldingBin\\";`

`smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;`

Comment: Here is a nearly identical question, however it is dated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306115/send-eml-files-saved-on-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer from gangelo

Another point:
The Pickup directory only works if there is some service (like IIS) picking up the mail messages stored there and sends them - so you need to configre IIS for this to work...

**EDIT - Exchange pickup folder as per comment:**

for example with Exchange 2007
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/management-administration/exchange-pickup-folder.html

and for Exhange 2010 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124230.aspx

Comment: I have a rather unique setup.  I am not using the IISPickupDirectory but a local one.  I have a service that runs on each users laptop that detects when they are back on OUR network which then triggers some events that were stored when they were offline.  I would be adding the "routine" for sending off the `.eml`s in this process.

Comment: So in that routine you just need to copy the mails from the local folder to central pickup folder once the users are back - never tried it but should work...

Comment: Interesting, so the Exchange Server itself has a pickup folder and I just need to identify that.  I will look into this.

Comment: This works slick.  My program creates the .eml's(with attachment included) and stores them in a local, user, folder and then after detecting our network moves the physical files to the Exchange Pickup Folder where Exchange automatically processes them.  Works slick!

Answer (score 4):

Files stored using the [`PickupDirectoryLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.pickupdirectorylocation.aspx) are written in raw SMTP (MIME/EML) format and are meant to be processed by the local SMTP server which is typically IIS. While the `SmtpClient` and the `MailMessage` objects can effectively "write" as raw SMTP/MIME they have no provision for reading such files. If you must read these files you'll need to write your own parser or use [one already created such as this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/EML_ReaderEx.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call smtpClient.Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage) but not before setting From, To, Subject and Body properties of System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.