# How do i send an email when i already have it as a string?

Tags: c#, email, tcpclient, smtpclient

Effectively I'm trying to send some template emails so that I can test a few components that handle reading from mailboxes.

I could just load up outlook and send a couple of emails but I'm looking to find a solution that can read thousands of emails at a time so I need to bulk send these templates t test the reading code.

When I say bulk send ... I have about 10 to 15 templates (varies) and I want to send about 1,000 copies of each to the given mailbox.

Now here's th sticking point ...

I could just fire up an instance of the SMTP client and declare a new `MailMessage` object then send that using the SMTP client ... the problem is that my email templates contain custom header info so its not just a matter of `msg.Body = someText` and then setting the To and From and Subject fields.

I don't want to spend time manually parsing these emails because the headers are quite lengthy and contain a lot of custom values that I'll be working on later.

So if I have a `txt` or `eml` file how do I send that raw text to my mailbox so I can perform my afformentioned testing?

Comment: You may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306115/send-eml-files-saved-on-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I know to do this is using MailBee.NET objects which are not free, but you can download a trial: http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components

Then what you are looking for is something like this:

```
            MailBee.Mime.MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.LoadMessage(filestream);
            MailBee.SmtpMail.Smtp.QuickSend(message);
```

Disclosure: I don't work for AfterLogic, but some of their tools have been a big help with Elastic Email (http://elasticemail.com)

Comment: Yeh there's quite a few of these "mail components" i was hoping to roll my own to save the $500 bill, i have now solved the problem using something called SMTP Express from a company called QuickSoft. It's a product we already have internally so there was no cost, all i do is dump my raw string to a file named anything.eml in a given pickup directory and it does the grunt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a well-formed RFC822 message, just transfer it as-is in the DATA phase of the SMTP transaction. On Unix, it's basically just

```
sendmail -oi -t <file
```

On some Linux distros, `sendmail` is not installed on the PATH; try `/usr/lib/sendmail` or consult a forum for your particular distro if you cannot come up with a few informed guesses on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Another one that came up in my search is [EASendMail](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/) by Email Architect. Like MailBee.NET it's not free but I have found [specific documentation](http://www.emailarchitect.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=71) that shows of the feature you are asking for by calling the SendRawMail method. That example is in C++/CLI but the same would apply to code written in C# or VB.NET. If I end up using trial to test it out I'll post my feedback here.