# Is there a free .eml parser available somewhere?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, eml

I am writing an add-on for my intranet to allow my users to just email "itsupport" and parse the from as the user who logged the job and the body as the issue.

Does anyone know if their is a free parser available so I don't have to look at writing something myself? (no point re-inventing the wheel right :) )

Thanks for any advice / links / suggestions. 
Barry

Comment: Hi, sorry. This is using vb.net

Comment: Try look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936422/recommendations-on-parsing-eml-files-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used it myself but you could try the approach described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mime_project.aspx