# GMail API parse message in .net

Tags: parsing, gmail-api

How can I parse a message to extract from, to, subject, body, attachments, embedded image, etc.from a message.
I want to extract all pieces of my message to create in another system a new message. 
I retrieve my message with this code but i can't parse it:

```
Dim myMailRequest = myGMailService.Users.Messages.Get("pgsolutionssyged@gmail.com", Message.Id)
myMailRequest.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Full
Dim gmailMessage As Message = myMailRequest.Execute
```

Comment: While sending request to messages.get, are you giving format='full'? Also, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669797/are-there-net-framework-methods-to-parse-an-email-mime

Comment: Yess i give format="full". Now i want to parse message object returned by GMail api