# need to open an image open in web browser

Tags: c#, parsing, mime

byte.eml file is  having image base64 encoded value ..and i am tring to open it in browser ...but this is not populating image file....plz help me out..

this is code...
 Dim oFile As System.IO.File
    Dim orEAD As System.IO.StreamReader

```
orEAD = oFile.OpenText("E:\mailbox\P3_hemantd.mbx\byte.eml")
Dim content As String
content = ""

''Dim intsinglechr As Integer
''Dim csinglechr As String

While orEAD.Peek <> -1
   content = content & Chr(orEAD.Read)
    content = Replace(content, vbCrLf, "")
    content = Replace(content, vbTab, "")
    content = Replace(content, " ", "")

End While
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
Response.BinaryWrite(Convert.FromBase64String(content))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does function Convert.FromBase64String(content) work correct? Try write to file it.

Comment: its working but it generating but result is unexpected....eg

����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 85 ��C  !"$"$

an i suppose to write it like ...this give error
Response.WriteFile(Convert.FromBase64String(content))

error.
value of type '1-dimensional array of byte'  cannot be converted to 'String'

one thing i want yoou to clear byte.eml file only having the base 64 encded image file.i try it to convert from diff utility this working .so need asp.net codeing for handling file based decoding

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content of `byte.eml` is not a base64 encoded image, it is a MIME document.

You need to parse the MIME document and *then* get your image.

You can google "C# MIME MAIL PARSING".

Here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936422/recommendations-on-parsing-eml-files-in-c) to get you started

**UPDATE**:

Ok, so let's assume that you actually do have a valid representation of an image as a base64 string...

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        Dim bytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("Chrysanthemum.jpg"))
        Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)

        '' base64 is what you say you have


        Dim newBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        Response.BinaryWrite(newBytes)
        Response.End()

    End Sub

</script>
```

This code works, if you substitute the text you have for `base64` and it doesn't work, you have not a valid base64 string representation of an image.

**Update 2**:

This will read the text file that you say contains base64 and write it to the response.

If it still does not work then you have another question to ask:

*How do I properly extract a base64 section from a MIME email?*

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim base64 As String = File.ReadAllText("E:\mailbox\P3_hemantd.mbx\byte.eml")

        Dim newBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64)
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        Response.BinaryWrite(newBytes)
        Response.End()
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: byte.eml file having only base 64 encoded image...i extract it from eml file .and now i am tring it to open in web browser through asp.net....but i am not getting result...help me suppose i am having txt file content base 64 encoded image.eg

"R0lGODlhagAwAOZ/ANHU+uLj4wZ0b4yT+oaHitfX11hj+H+H+xMn6Oj29xzVy9L19BHGvauw+zVF
8sjIyEhV+Efaz2pvozKf3b29vQ0m1v7+/u7u7gWJgwlgqoOzsSo67yTd0yXXzODi+wV/..........."

so send my exact asp.net code for converting abouve base 64 encoded text to image .

Comment: boss you are great...i tried your code ..and its working...i bit happy after spending 10 hour something got happening.... let see 

what my code say.... 

will you help me once more..... 

send me code for read txt file content and convert it Byte 

i am asking for replacement of this.. 


Dim bytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("Chrysanthemum.jpg")) Dim base64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) 
i want to store in base64 my file content

Comment: thanks frnd i got solved my problem....
thanks  alot......i need your mail...for further any help...

Comment: @Manish - great, glad I could help. Welcome to StackOverflow. Now, I did my job in helping you, your job is to click the up arrow next to the '0' that is next to my answer to indicate pleasure with my answer and then click the check mark to indicate that this answer helped you solve your problem.