# Saving emails to .eml file using specifiedPickupDirectory creates double decimal points in email body

Tags: c#, email, save, app-config, decimal-point

I want to verify email body content in .eml files saved to disk.
I have added the following section to my App.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="d:\temp\emails\"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Sometimes some of the body content in the .eml  file is saved incorrectly.
I have some values that are being saved with double decimal points

Example:

```
ABC, XYZ, 2.00, 0..19609, 0.2117772
```

When I take out the config section and the email is sent to my outlook inbox, I do not get this issue. 
Example:

```
ABC, XYZ, 2.00, 0.19609, 0.2117772
```

It is always the same values that are correct and incorrect.
I wouldn't expect that the saving of a file would modify content.
Any help on what might be happening here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, this is to be expected as the file produced is not supposed to be a straight copy but rather follow the rfc822 spec (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/3_Lexical.html).

If you want to compare the file output with your input, then I think you will need to find/write a routine to decode the rfc822 back to plain test.

Comment: Thanks for the information. That is useful to know and it does seem that this spec shows the decimal point as a special character. I am currently looking for a c# routine to decode rfc822 back to plain text if anybody knows of one. I noticed that when I open the .eml file in notepad the the following header was set "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936422/recommendations-on-parsing-eml-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can't use the accepted answer in this link as a solution as I'm running Windows 7. I am actually using the LumiSoft Mime parser mentioned but this has the doudle decimal point issue in the mimeEntity.DataText property. It's probably worth trying different mime parsers mentioned in the link.

Comment: I've tried to use another Mime parser in the link provided (Sasa) and got the same issue.
I looked for code to decode the rfc822 back to plain test without any luck-Used: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11380/A-C-Implementation-of-Mime-De-encode

When I opened the .eml file with notepad, the double decimal point issue only appeared for values where the first character of the line was a decimal place.
Example:
ABC, XYZ, 2.00, 0=
..19609, 0.2117772,

For now I resorted to a hack (emailLineRead.Replace("..", ".")) to remove the unexpected behaviour but this is obviously not what I want to do.

Comment: Maybe I am getting mixed up with my rfcs. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602318/system-net-mail-creating-invalid-emails-and-eml-files-inserting-extra-dots-in-h

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly the information I was looking for. I got side tracked with other work and didn't see your update until now.