# Unable to attach an eml file as an attachment when sending an email using c#?

Tags: c#, email, stream, email-attachments, eml

I am receiving emails through `hmailserver` and sending those emails as **.eml** file as an attachment of another report email.

I am having issues in reading and sending those emails as an attachment.

This is what I am doing.

```
public void addAttachment(string pathname, bool retry)
    {
        string attachmentname = "";
        do
        {
            try
            {
                attachmentname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathname);
                Stream file = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(pathname));
                Log.WriteMessage("Size" + file.Length);
                dtstreamAttach.Add(attachmentname+".eml", file);
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                string strCurrentTs = DateTime.Now.ToString(strDateFormat);
                attachmentname = attachmentname + "-" + strCurrentTs+".eml";
            }
        } while (retry);
    }
```

Then,

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            . 
            .
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(kvp.Value, kvp.Key)); // I have an attachment dictionary 
            string contenttype = GetMimeType(".eml");
            ContentType cnttype = new ContentType(contenttype);
            message.Attachments[0].ContentType = cnttype;
```

as you see i print the **Stream size** - which prints out as something like **4790Bytes (4KB)**
But when i receive the email, i only get an eml file with **size 1KB and the eml file is empty**.

I have checked the file paths and also made sure that the email is there until my report mail is sent out.
I have also verified content type is `message/rfc822`.

Everything seems to check out. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936422/recommendations-on-parsing-eml-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: @NullReferenceException I dont need to parse eml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it. Looks like the `MemoryStream` have the correct stream and also the `ContentStream` of the message object has the correct sizes, but the Stream **postion had moved to the end of the stream** and hence when the message is actually being sent, it actualy has nothing.

So **make sure to reposition the stream back to origin** before adding it to `AttachmentCollection`, something like

`Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`

especially when using streams wrapped in dlls, something might have moved them.