# extract attachment from eml file saved in local system using c#

Tags: c#, parsing, mime, eml

I am trying to get the attachment from an .eml file.

The eml file is saved locally in my machine. I need to extract the attachment and attach it to MailMessage.

Able to attach the whole .eml file like below

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
//storing the .eml into this ms 'memory stream'
ms.Position = 0;
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, attachmentName));
```

But, i only need the attachment which is inside this .eml file. How to get that ? (As a memorystream)

---Edit---

Need to load the attachment which is inside the .eml file into the memorystream.

---Edit---

I found this qn somewhat similar.
[EML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936422/recommendations-on-parsing-eml-files-in-c-sharp)

[Advanced MIME Parser/Creator/Editor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11882/Advanced-MIME-Parser-Creator-Editor)

But, couldn't get the proper solution to my problem.
I think below is the issue.

Gets attachment entities. Entity is considered as attachmnet if:

*) Content-Disposition: attachment (RFC 2822 message)

*) Content-Disposition: filename = "" is specified (RFC 2822 message)

*) Content-Type: name = "" is specified (old RFC 822 message)

Comment: @mjwills thanks for the comment.I need to load the attachment which is inside an .eml file.

Comment: At first glance [LEML](https://github.com/HiraokaHyperTools/LEML) (or [on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LEML/)) will do this, although it returns a byte array not a stream.

Comment: @Rup could you please give a link to an exapmle. So, that it will be easy to understand how to use it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). The GitHub page for MimeKit has a number of examples on how to create and parse MIME messages, how to get attachments, etc. The `FAQ.md` has additional examples to answer common questions. If you need more help, send me an email (listed on the GitHub account page) and I'll help you out.